# Why is this question still around?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, new-users, spam

I'm talking about [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294394/building-computer-programs-for-analyzing-abstract-strategy-games). The user is obviously a troll and should probably be question-locked and some serious action taken to limit their ability to comment.

I flagged it for moderator attention, no bones.

Comment: I know that it's a Sunday and that the moderators probably aren't constantly patrolling the site, so I apologize the unnecessary sense of urgency.

Comment: @Yannis Thank you!

Comment: Chris, regarding a comment you left on the question: While I agree that the asker's behaviour was completely unjustified, I don't think telling him to leave the StackExchange network was the right thing to do.

Comment: @MetaFight Possibly not, but an obvious troll is an obvious troll, and do people who troll actually participate on the network in any way valuable to the community? Personally, I don't think he ever would.

Comment: It's not guaranteed he was a troll.  I've seen people with mental health issues react that way too.  Regardless, I don't think we should be rude to be people who offend us.

Comment: @MetaFight Well, in that case, my bad.

Comment: And yes, I'm a hypocrite when I say that.  I've said some pretty mean stuff on here... that's something I'm trying to change.

Comment: @MetaFight [quoting self](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260782/165773), "These posts damage site image no matter if there are snarky comments there or not... If one worries about snarky comments in posts like that, well the real solution is simply to delete these posts - the sooner the better. Whatever comments are there will be deleted along the way, making it not an issue."

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, but it really doesn't matter ;P  Even if the question is definitely going to be deleted, we should still hold back from being rude because new members might see regular members being rude and that creates a poor image of the community.  Yes, it's a very unlikely situation, but better safe than sorry.  Also, personally, if I allow myself to be rude in specific situations it's harder for me to keep it polite the rest of the time :)

Comment: @MetaFight I disagree with myself here :) ...in the sense that I try to abstain of snarky comments myself. However, in posts like that I just don't feel like blaming others when they can't hold their emotions (for comparison, in less troublesome posts, even low quality, I happily flag snarky stuff and feel good about doing this)

Comment: Ah yes, I see.  That's a very good point!

Comment: 68 comments on that [now-deleted] question... wow.